# Rails associations with lookup table that has a two column primary key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

CD table looks something like this:

```
cd.dogtag (primary key)
...
```

`cd_tracks` has `id` and `tracks` (track name), example:

```
1   Turd On The Run
```

`cd_tracks2title` is a lookup table to join many to many from the CD table and the `cd_tracks` table. But it also contains info I want to get:

```
cd_tracks2title.dogTag
cd_tracks2title.trackId
cd_tracks2title.duration
cd_tracks2title.position
```

The primary key for `cd_tracks2title` is in fact 2 columns:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`dogTag`,`trackId`)
```

And the data inside `cd_tracks2title` might look like this:

```
1   4   NULL    NULL    3:24    11
```

The problem is I'm trying to establish a Rails association from CD table to cd_tracks2title using those 2 primary columns, but there doesn't seem to be a way.

If I do this:

```
# cd_track.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :cd, :join_table => 'cd_tracks2title', :foreign_key => 'trackId', :association_foreign_key => 'dogTag'

#cd.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :cd_track, :join_table => 'cd_tracks2title', :foreign_key => 'dogTag', :association_foreign_key => 'trackId'
```

That's fine and I can get the track names with something like `Cd.first.cd_track`, but I don't have a way to get the `cd_tracks2title.duration` and `cd_tracks2title.position` info since it's a simple lookup table.

Ideally, I'd keep this association so I can still get the track name, but would need another association from the CD table to the `cd_tracks2title` table, via the `cd_tracks` table using both the `cd.dogTag` and `cd_tracks.id` values to get the correct information.

Of course, I used to do all this by explicitly writing out the Mysql JOINs in the query, but I'd like to create the Rails associtaion.

Comment: Realy, no way to do this? not even with a gem?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I opted to redesign the database and include a separate ID field as a single primary key. While using compound keys as primarys doesn't violate any database design conventions, ActiveRecord expects each table to have a single, unique primary key and it does make things easier so I've done that.

Still, I'm surprised there isn't a way to handle this natively in AR since it's not an uncommon occurrence.